# Microsoft Azure Pipeline Error: "No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted"

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am trying to implement CI/CD for my private project on Azure. I also have upgraded my subscription to "pay as you go". When I try to save and queue my pipeline, I get the error
##[error]No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted. To request a free parallelism grant, please fill out the following form https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request.

Since I already can see 1 self hosted free parallel job(0 MS hosted parallel jobs) why can't they be used? Is there anything I am missing. Although I have already raised a request for parallelism request, is it really required?

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68405027/how-to-resolve-no-hosted-parallelism-has-been-purchased-or-granted-in-free-tie/68405383#68405383

Answer (score 0):

This was introduced because they were having issues with some user(s) creating multiple free accounts and effectively taking advantage of the free offer or using it in a way for which it was not intended. You will be able to use a free agent once your request gets processed.

If you want to start using pipelines immediately you can purchase a paid agent, go to Organization Settings, Parallel Jobs and at the top under Private Projects click Purchase parallel jobs. On the next screen put a 1 (or more) in the top right hand box:

[image: Pipelines for private projects]

Now scroll to the bottom and click Save and you should be good to go.

Comment: But I have upgraded my subscription from free tier to paid. In this case too I will have to wait for approval?

Comment: It sounds like you've upgraded your Azure subscription - you would need to add a paid pipeline, I'll update my answer.