# Azure pipelines not running

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, agent

I've got a free tier Azure Cloud Account. I used to have a project and requested a free agent for running pipelines. All was ok.

I deleted that project and created a new one.
I'm now trying to create a very basic Hello World kind of pipeline and getting it to run, to test things. The pipeline fails to run with the error below.

**Error Message: No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted. To request a free parallelism grant, please fill out the following form https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request**

I can see in my organization settings that I have that free agent available and 1800 mins/month of run time available. But i think that agent isn't getting used/found by my pipeline jobs.

I'm a noob at azure, so pardon me for any goof ups in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve "No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted" in free tier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68405027/how-to-resolve-no-hosted-parallelism-has-been-purchased-or-granted-in-free-tie)

Comment: you have to fill the form and wait for 2 working days. Microsoft support will drop you a mail after completion.

Comment: To answer @Manish. I had done that in the past and i was given access to an agent. But that was when i had another project.

Comment: Solution: Just after posting this question, I thought of creating another project and make it private. I then ran a sample pipeline and it worked. So basically, my issue was that the pipeline granted to me was for a private project and not a public one. I had forgotten about it as i was revising azure after some time.

Comment: if you create a new organization you have to request again..

Comment: @Manish: The organization is the same. The project was new. I think my problem was I created the project as a public project.

Answer (score 1):

You just write message to https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request with your name, email, project etc. and after 24-48 hours you can run your pipeline

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft comes with some temporary alternative approach until the automate is implemented to grant the permission for those users who requires the free hosted agent pools.

Now users needs to be drop the email to get the free tier access based on the project visibility types.

There is not a standard timeline for approval which someone can predict approval in days, but by considering the mass requests and manual approval process we can consider the timeline of 7 to 15 working days from your email.

For More information -> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-private-projects/

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer :)

Comment: @ASanghvi could you please mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Just after posting this question, I thought of creating another project and make it private. I then ran a sample pipeline and it worked. So basically, my issue was that the pipeline granted to me was for a private project and not a public one. I had forgotten about it as i was revising azure after some time.